# Find overlapping of dates: How to find the dates of the user overlaps with other users in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

If the date of the users overlaps with other users then it should update as Overlap for that user else as No_overlap in a new column.

Code for creating table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dates_range (
    `User` VARCHAR(2) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `start_date` DATE,
    `end_date` DATE
);
INSERT INTO dates_range VALUES
    ('U1','2020-01-01','2020-01-31'),
    ('U2','2020-01-16','2020-01-26'),
    ('U3','2020-01-28','2020-02-06'),
    ('U4','2020-02-16','2020-02-26');
```

Its output is:

```
User    start_date      end_date
U1      2020-01-01      2020-01-31
U2      2020-01-16      2020-01-26
U3      2020-01-28      2020-02-06
U4      2020-02-16      2020-02-26
```

Want the output like:

```
   User     status
   U1       Overlap
   U2       Overlap
   U3       Overlap
   U4       No_Overlap
```

Please help with the easiest method to find the overlapping, I'm naive in sql and having difficulty in understanding and finding overlapping of dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using exists logic along with the formula for overlapping date ranges we can try:

```sql
SELECT User,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dates_range dr2
                         WHERE dr2.start_date < dr1.end_date AND
                               dr2.end_date > dr1.start_date AND
                               dr2.User <> dr1.User)
            THEN 'Overlap' ELSE 'No_Overlap' END AS status
FROM dates_range dr1
ORDER BY User;
```

Comment: @MohammedAsif Sorry, my exists logic was missing a check on the user.  [Check the demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=326adfb9162061f4c84d923ea6253c49) to see the logic working